# Nlog does not recognize last file of the day as archive

Tags: archive, nlog

Using nlog, I want to create an archive file every hour and keep archive files for one week. I'm using the nlog archive functionality, with archiveEvery set to "Hour" and maxArchiveFiles set to "168".

```
<target xsi:type="File"
        name="fileLog"
        fileName="D:\EventLogs\Logs\MyLog_${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"
        archiveFileName="D:\EventLogs\Logs\MyLog.{#}.log"
        archiveEvery="Hour"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd hh.mm"
        maxArchiveFiles="168"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        />
```

This works except that the last file of the day is not getting recognized as an archive, it just keeps its original file name and does not ever get deleted. Why does this happen only to the last file of the day?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by removing the ${shortdate} from the fileName. I see now that a new file was being created when the new day changed, before the file would get archived by nlog.

```
<target xsi:type="File"
       name="fileLog"
       fileName="D:\EventLogs\Logs\MyLog.log"
       layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"
       archiveFileName="D:\EventLogs\Logs\MyLog.{#}.log"
       archiveEvery="Hour"
       archiveNumbering="Date"
       archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd hh.mm"
       maxArchiveFiles="168"
       keepFileOpen="false"
       />
```

Comment: THANK YOU this has ended an hour of frustration.